# How do i implement GSM geolocalisation?

Tags: gps

I am working on a project that might need to use GSM geolocalisation instead of GNSS. The problem is I have never implemented something like that.

A lot of systems using this technology, seem relatively affordable so I doubt the companies selling them are paying monthly fees to operators.

Do I need to subscribe to an operator like I would with a cell phone? If no, how do i access the services I need?